# Documentation on Virt-ICE other than white paper

Tags: security, debugging, malware, qemu

I am trying to find information on Virt-ICE, a malware debugger/analysis tool presented at the most recent [Black Hat conference](http://blackhat.com/). I have read through the white paper [Virt-ICE: Next-generation Debugger for Malware Analysis](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-10/whitepapers/Anh/BlackHat-USA-2010-Anh-Virt-ICE-wp.pdf) and am now looking for something more. It sounds fascinating and I would love to dig deeper.

Here is what I have found:

- [Neat poster summary](http://www.rcis.aist.go.jp/files/events/2010/0514-ja/VICE-poster.pdf)
- Seminal paper: [Virt-ICE: Next-generation Debugger for Malware Analysis](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-10/whitepapers/Anh/BlackHat-USA-2010-Anh-Virt-ICE-wp.pdf)
- [Presentation slides from Black Hat](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-10/presentations/Anh/BlackHat-USA-2010-Anh-Virt-ICE-slides.pdf)

Comment: This is pretty cool, but I doubt there is much more info on it since it was just presented at defcon a few days ago. You could try e-mailing the authors.

Comment: As I find material, I will update the question with what I find and hopefully someone will chime in with something I HAVEN'T posted so I can have someone to mark as answering the question...

Answer (score 1):

I was at Black hat and somebody asked when it was going to be released and the authors said TBD... aka.... you'll probably be waiting a few months.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will check back in soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think it only focuses on being stealth ... but they don't help on providing a good analysis tool ... I mean it doesn't give some AI for example or some tools making the malware analyzing more faster and easier.

am I true?